# IP_CONNTRACK vs NF_CONNTRACK

Tags: linux, tcp, debian, ipv4, conntrack

I've a problem with a high load situation with two load balancers using NGINX. I want to tune some TCP parameters and get stuck with it.

```
# sysctl -a | grep fin
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 60
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
```

So there are parameters for `ip_conntrack` and `nf_conntrack` and there is also a third variable. Which of them do I have to set up? Distribution is Debian Wheezy.